# Set value of checkbox to false

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to set the value of a checkbox to false where the value of textbox1 is equal to item# in the table I have the checkbox in. I need to do this via a command button click. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you give some sample code or add a small table to your question that demonstrates more visually what you are trying to do? Right now I'm not 100% sure what you are asking.

Comment: I simply need to modify the value of a check box in a table from a form. This needs to be done from a button and only modify the record that matches a text box on the form. please  let me know if this cleared things up.

Comment: Do you mean change the label for the checkbox or change its value from unchecked to checked? Also is this in a Userform or on an actual excel worksheet?

Comment: Changed its value from check to unchecked. and It is a user form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your userform's `CommandButton1_click()` event and it should work.

```
If TextBoxName.Value = "Value of item you are comparing to" Then
    CheckBoxName.Value = False
End If
```

You need to change certain things in this code like adding the name of the text box, name of the check box, and entering the value of the item you want to compare it to.